# Declare parameterized query in markup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic, parameters

I'm trying to convert a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express query in ASP-Classic that is not parameterized so I did the following (see code below) but I keep getting an error saying:

> *Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Parameters'*

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong!

Thanks!

```
<%
' OPEN DATABASE
dim objConn, objRS, objTRS, objUnit
dim strConnection
set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MSSQLSrv;Database=DbTest;UID=blablabala;PWD=blablabala"
objConn.Open strConnection
set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set objRS.ActiveConnection = objConn
strQuery = "SELECT USERNAME,PASSWORD from CUSTOMERS where EMAIL=?"
objRS.Parameters(0) = Request.QueryString("email")
objRS.Open strQuery
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    ' OPEN DATABASE
    dim objConn,objRS,objTRS,objUnit

   Const adCmdText = &H0001

    Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
    objConn.ActiveConnection = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MSSQLSrv;Database=DbTest;UID=blablabala;PWD=blablabala"

   objConn.CommandType = adCmdText

    strQuery = "SELECT USERNAME,PASSWORD from CUSTOMERS where EMAIL=?"
    objConn.CommandText=strQuery 
    objConn.Parameters(0) = Request.QueryString("email")
    SET objRS = objConn.execute(strQuery)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying make it a parameter query, then you need to create the command object and parameters first. For example:

```
' create your command object
Const adCmdText = &H0001
Set objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCmd.ActiveConnection = YourConnectionString
objCmd.CommandType = adCmdText    ' Evaluate as textual definition, not stored procedure

'now create query and add parameters
strQuery = "SELECT USERNAME,PASSWORD from CUSTOMERS where EMAIL=?"  
objCmd.CommandText=strQuery
objCmd.Parameters.Append = objCmd.CreateParameter("ParameterName", ParameterType, adParamInput,   parameterSize, ParameterValue)
SET objRS = objCmd.execute(strSQL)
Set objCmd=Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameters collection is on the `command` object not the `recordset`.

Here is some VB6 code that works, the parameter name is not important as parameter order is all that counts.

```
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New Command

    With cmd
        .CommandText = "SELECT USERNAME,PASSWORD from CUSTOMERS where EMAIL=?" ' this proc also returns factor info
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        Set .ActiveConnection = objconn
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Email", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "Email")

        Set rst = cmd.Execute
    End With
```